# Extended Wi-Fi but 1 trouble maybe more

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've extended my wifi downstairs using a lan to lan connection from the root router upstairs. The second router has dhcp disabled and I can transition connections seamlessly from downstairs to upstairs and vice versa. Many times people come over and tend to hog the download speeds. Is there a way I can limit download speeds for each person for the two routers?

Comment: What kind of routers? QoS and bandwidth management would be a function of the primary (root in your post) router. It would have to be capable of managing that. Some consumer routers have this capability, others do not or have limited functionality. Without knowing more we can't really say if it is possible or not.

Comment: Oh QoS on the root router now that makes sense since I was confused with setting it up on the second router. However I've tried searching for QoS on my root router (Huawei HG8245Q) but haven't seen any setting like it or even close. Maybe that's what lead me to setup qos on the second router (TP-LINK TL-WR940N/TL-WR941ND) hmmmmmm.

Comment: The second router really has nothing to QoS on since there is no connection to the WAN to prioritize traffic to. The Huawei router is very much a limited consumer grade ONT, not much you can do but turn it on according to http://setuprouter.com/router/huawei/hg8245/manual-165.pdf there is just an on and off and no configuration. Sorry, but you are likely out of luck other than to limit who can use WiFi and who can't by changing the passcode and only give it to trusted individuals.

Comment: What if I disable the wifi of the root router and put the secondary router upstairs next to it and do a lan to wan connection (and use this as my root connection) with dhcp enabled and put a different one downstairs using a lan to lan with dhcp connection disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could enable Quality of Service (QoS) management on the master router, provided it supports the feature. QoS attempts to even out these types of problems and even allows you to set up device and protocol priorities. If you have a fairly new router, chances are it supports this feature.

Comment: I have WMM enabled by default on my root router, what does that do?

Comment: WMM appears to be a type of QoS mainly focused on providing optimal multimedia performance to multiple users connected to the routers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Multimedia_Extensions
However since it's enabled on your router by default my initial suggestion no longer applies.

Comment: If I was to set up QoS on my root router (dhcp enabled) so that it can take effect on users using the second router via a lan to lan connection with dhcp enabled, how would I go about doing that ?

Comment: I don't know your router's admin interface so you'll have to look that up, but the setting can usually be found in advanced settings and it might be called QoS, WMM or even something plain like bandwidth settings/rules. There's usually a priority or a bandwidth based setting. Bandwidth setting lets you set the min ensured or max allowed bandwidth for an IP/port config. In case of the priority based setting, you just assign priorities to IPs/ports. You'll also have to set up DHCP reservations for your devices to ensure that the DHCP server always assigns the same address to a device.

Comment: Thanks @rxj will try it out back can you explain to me how does users that are connected to my connection downstairs with dhcp disabled register themselves on the router. Is it that there ip address is that of the ranges of the root router and can be found on the router main page through the second router?

Comment: No DHCP on the second router is ok, because it just forwards everything to the master router, which will assign IPs as per usual. In order to set a priority or bandwidth limit on guests, I would suggest keeping all your DHCP reservations at the beginning of the address pool and making a rule for the remaining IP range. Imagine your address pool is 192.168.0.100-to-200 and you have 3 regular devices. Set the device IPs to .100,101,102 and set up rules for each of them. Next, set up a rule for the rest of the IP range (103-200) which are the IPs that will be assigned to new devices (guests).